# Passar parâmetro de uma Page para outra React Native

Tags: react-native, expo

Tenho uma pagina de login e outra com uma webview, não estou conseguindo passar um parâmetro da pagina de login para outra página com a webview.

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import Routes from "./Routes";

export default function App() {
  return <Routes />;
}
```

Routes.js

```
import React from "react";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";

import Login from "./pages/Login";
import WebViewSite from "./pages/WebViewSite";

const AppStack = createStackNavigator();

export default function Routes() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <AppStack.Navigator>
        <AppStack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
        <AppStack.Screen name="WebViewSite" component={WebViewSite} />
      </AppStack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Login/index.js   Esse envia o parâmetro

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
    KeyboardAvoidingView,
    View,
    Text,
    Image,
    TextInput,
    TouchableOpacity,
    StatusBar,
    Animated,
    Keyboard,
    Alert
} from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";

import styles from './styles';
import logo from '../../assets/Logo.png';
import config from '../../config';
import api from '../../services/api';
//import servicos from '../../services/services';

export default function Login() {
    const [usuario, setUsuario] = useState('');
    const [senha, setSenha] = useState('');

    const navigation = useNavigation();

    function navigateToWebViewPar(url) {
        navigation.navigate('WebViewSite', { link: 'https://github.com/' });
    }


    function Login() {
        api.get('/disponibilidade/status_clienteapp')
            .then(function (res) {
                if (res.status == 200) {
                    RetornaLink()
                } else {

                }
                //console.log(response.status);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }


    function RetornaLink() {
        if (!usuario) {
            Alert.alert('Atenção', 'Informe o Usuário!')
        } else {
            if (!senha) {
                Alert.alert('Atenção', 'Informe a Senha!')
            } else {
                api.get('/login/verifica_cadastro/'.concat("", usuario).concat("/", senha).concat("/", config.codEmpresa))
                    .then(function (response) {
                        var ret = response.data;
                        console.log(ret);
                        if (ret == 30) {
                            alert('Campo Usuario ou Senha Inválido.');
                        } else if (ret == 40) {
                            alert('Serviço Temporariamente Indisponível.');
                        } else if (ret == 50) {
                            alert('Erro Inesperado! Por favor tente novamente.');
                        } else {
                            navigateToWebViewPar(ret);
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    })
            }
        }

    }


    return (
        <>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <StatusBar backgroundColor="#d1dae1" />

                <View style={styles.containerLogo}>
                    <Image source={logo} style={styles.logo}></Image>
                    <View style={styles.AlinharOpcoes}>
                        <Text style={styles.nomeDaEmpresa}>{config.nomeEmpresa}</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.txtApp}>APP</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>

                <Text style={styles.txtInfo}>Faça login para iniciar sua sessão</Text>

                <TextInput
                    style={styles.input}
                    placeholder="Usuário"
                    keyboardType="numeric"
                    textContentType="none"
                    autoCapitalize="none"
                    // autoCompleteType="email"
                    autoCorrect={false}
                    onChangeText={(usuario) => setUsuario(usuario)}
                />

                <TextInput
                    style={styles.input}
                    placeholder="Senha"
                    //keyboardType="visible-password"
                    textContentType="password"
                    autoCapitalize="none"
                    autoCompleteType="password"
                    autoCorrect={false}
                    secureTextEntry={true}
                    onChangeText={(senha) => setSenha(senha)}
                />

                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonSubmit} onPress={Login}>
                    <Text style={styles.submitText}>Acessar</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>

                <View style={styles.AlinharOpcoes}>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonRegister}>
                        <Text style={styles.registerText}>Solicitar Acesso</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonResetPass}>
                        <Text style={styles.ResetPassText}>Esqueci Minha Senha</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>

                <Text style={styles.txRodape}>Desenvolvido por DinTec Sistemas</Text>

            </View>
        </>
    );
};
```

WebViewSite/index.js   Esse deveria receber o parâmetro

```
import React from "react";
import { useNavigation,  } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

export default class WebViewSite extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        name: this.props.navigation.getParam('link')   
    };
  }

  render() {
      return (
      <WebView source={{ uri: 'https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/' }} style={{ marginTop: 20 }} />
      );    
  }
}
```

Testei de várias maneiras e fica dando erro

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
> '_native.useNavigation.params.name')

e também

> TypeError: _this.props.navigation.getParam is not a function. (In
> '_this.props.navigation.getParam('link')',
> '_this.props.navigation.getParam' is undefined)

Não sei mais oque fazer, percorri toda a documentação mas não consegui resolver.

Answer (score 0):

De acordo com a própria documentação, você está fazendo tudo certo ao enviar o parâmetro, o erro está na hora de você pegar ele.
Na documentação, ao passar um parâmetro, você deve pegar ele com "route.params", nos props.
Sendo assim, seu código deve ficar parecido com isso:

```js
import React from "react";
import { useNavigation,  } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

export default class WebViewSite extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        name: this.props.route.params.link  
    };
  }

  render() {
      return (
      <WebView source={{ uri: 'https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/' }} style={{ marginTop: 20 }} />
      );    
  }
}
```

Em caso de dúvidas, vide a documentação do [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/)